# Why am I getting a 'receiver type mismatch' error for this code

Tags: generics, types, kotlin

Take a look at this code:

```
import Moves.*
import ReverseMoves.*

interface Move {
    val opp : Move
}

enum class Moves(override val opp: Move) : Move {
    U(U_),
    R(R_),
    L(L_),
    D(D_),
    F(F_),
    B(B_),
}

enum class ReverseMoves(override val opp: Move) : Move {
    U_(U),
    R_(R),
    L_(L),
    D_(D),
    F_(F),
    B_(B),
}
val cornerMapping: Map<Move, IntArray> = mutableMapOf(
    U to intArrayOf(1, 2, 4, 3),
    R to intArrayOf(2, 6, 8, 4),
    L to intArrayOf(1, 3, 7, 5),
    D to intArrayOf(7, 8, 6, 5),
    F to intArrayOf(3, 4, 8, 7),
    B to intArrayOf(2, 1, 5, 6)
)

fun f() {
    for (m in cornerMapping) {
        cornerMapping.set(m.key.opp, m.value.reversed().toIntArray())
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I try to compile this code:

```
t.kt:37:23: error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
@InlineOnly public inline operator fun <K, V> MutableMap<Move, IntArray>.set(key: Move, value: IntArray): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
@InlineOnly public inline operator fun kotlin.text.StringBuilder /* = java.lang.StringBuilder */.set(index: Int, value: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.text
        cornerMapping.set(m.key.opp, m.value.reversed().toIntArray())
                      ^
```

I can't see why I'm getting this error, the types of the key and value passed to `set` exactly match the ones declared for cornerMapping.

Comment: You should know that your code will experience problems with null. Due to circular dependencies it is impossible for your code to initialize without leaving some values `null` where they otherwise would have values. Since you first access `Moves` it is likely this means the `opp` field inside of the `ReverseMoves` instances will all be `null`.

Answer (score 5):

I guess there is no method `set` defined in `Map`. You can change type of `cornerMapping` variable to `MutableMap` and it will work:

```
val cornerMapping: MutableMap<Move, IntArray> = mutableMapOf(
    Moves.U to intArrayOf(1, 2, 4, 3),
    Moves.R to intArrayOf(2, 6, 8, 4),
    Moves.L to intArrayOf(1, 3, 7, 5),
    Moves.D to intArrayOf(7, 8, 6, 5),
    Moves.F to intArrayOf(3, 4, 8, 7),
    Moves.B to intArrayOf(2, 1, 5, 6)
)

fun f() {
    for (m in cornerMapping) {
        cornerMapping[m.key.opp] = m.value.reversed().toIntArray()
    }
}
```

It is because methods in `Map` interface support only read-only access to the map; read-write access is supported through the `MutableMap` interface.